# Why is an equals condition required when filtering with NOT EXISTS in SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a catalogue of products and a list of customer orders for these products.
I want to find the products which haven't had an order yet and tried this in SQLite:

```
SELECT  product_id
FROM    products p
WHERE   NOT EXISTS    (SELECT product_id FROM orders ord)
```

However, this simply produces the entire list of products p without any filtering. Why does the solution below work but the above doesn't?

```
SELECT  product_id
FROM    products p
WHERE   NOT EXISTS    (SELECT product_id FROM orders ord
                       WHERE p.product_id = ord.product_id)
```

Comment: `SELECT product_id FROM products p WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT product_id FROM orders ord)` this can't return *the entire list of products* unless the table `orders` is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "equals" condition makes the subquery a *correlated* subquery.  Without it, `NOT EXISTS` works just fine.  It run the subquery and if the subquery returns *any* rows, then everything gets filtered out.

Presumably, `orders` has at least one row, so the subquery would *always* return one row (without the `EXISTS`).  Hence, the overall query returns the empty set.

With the correlated clause, each `product_id` is checked independently.  So the query returns products that have never been ordered.